# how do you program a calendar that can tell you the days ago/ from now (past/future dates) of a specific date you enter in

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, calendar

I am trying to program a calendar that checks how many days from now/ ago (past and present) from raw_input. I need a loop that counts the days through the current year and adds it to a variable called: Total_days and this loop has to go through each year until it hits the current date that the code ran on. The end result is that the output gives you the date you entered in a complete sentence: eg. "10/08/1700 was ___ days ago" Basically my teacher explained that the past days has to add up until it hits that certain date using a loop(loops are required. This is an assignment, i cant use any other functions like delta, but loops and datetime stuff is good!) and then for the future it has to say how many days from now until that futuristic date happens using loops. I am very stumped and i need your guys' help.
Heres what i got so far:

```
import datetime 
input_date = raw_input("Enter in full format (mm/dd/yyyy):")
year = input_date[6:10]
yeara = int(year)
montha = int(input_date[1:2])
daya = int(input_date[4:5])

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
now = datetime.now()
year = now.year

month = now.month
day = now.day


def isleapYear(year):


if year % 4 == 0:
    check =  True
if year % 100 == 0:
    check = False
if year % 400 == 0:
    check = True

total_days = 0
n = 12
moNum = [0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
while n > montha:
  if yeara > year:
    if year == isleapYear(year):
      total_days += 366
  elif year != isleapYear(year):
  total_days += 365 
  if montha == month:
  break
  total_days += int(moNum[n])
  if n == 02:
    if isleapYear(year) == True:
    total_days += 1


n -= 1

ny = 365
h = total_days
if yeara > year:
  if year == isleapYear(year):
    total_days += 366
elif year != isleapYear(year):
  total_days += 365 

if yeara>year:
time = "future"
if yeara<year:
time = "past"
if yeara==year:
if montha>month:
    time = "future"
if montha<month:
    time = past
if montha == month:
    if daya>day:
        time = "future"
    if daya<day:
        time = "past"
    if daya==day:
        time = "present"
print str(h.days) + " days in the " + str(time)
```

Thanks for helping out! i appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated code, with everything fixed:

```
import datetime 
input_date = raw_input("Enter in full format (mm/dd/yyyy):")
year = input_date[6:10]
yeara = int(year)
montha = int(input_date[1:2])
daya = int(input_date[4:5])

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
now = datetime.now()
year = now.year

month = now.month
day = now.day


def isleapYear(year):


    if year % 4 == 0:
        check =  True
    if year % 100 == 0:
        check = False
    if year % 400 == 0:
        check = True


end_date = input_date
start_date = now

delta = date(year,month,day)
delta2 = date(yeara,montha,daya)
h = delta-delta2
if yeara>year:
    time = "future"
if yeara<year:
    time = "past"
if yeara==year:
    if montha>month:
        time = "future"
    if montha<month:
        time = past
    if montha == month:
        if daya>day:
            time = "future"
        if daya<day:
            time = "past"
        if daya==day:
            time = "present"
print str(h.days) + " in the " + str(time)
```

The most important thing that you forgot is that there are functions in datetime that will automatically find the number of days till the input...

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: also, he wants me to use loops, as practice. This works though, but in a different type of way than what my teacher expects. Also, the days should be positive in the output when it says ___ (days)  in the future. It wouldn't make sense if it said eg: -2000 days in the future

Comment: So basically my teacher wants a code that will count from the date of now to the input date using loops. A few loops will need to count how many days in each month while having leapyear as a function for these loops and then adding that to the total_days. And then the end of the loops is when the loops hits the current date. the (past) loop is supposed to count how many days till the current date and then add that to the total days, which will be displayed in the "days in the past" after all the loops break. And then same goes for future but with a little bit of a difference in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Must you use a loop? Else, you can build from the following:

```
refdatestr = "2010/08/23"
refdate = datetime.strptime(refdatestr, "%Y/%m/%d")
now = datetime.now()
difference_days = (now-refdate).days
```

`difference_days` is a `datetime.timedelta` object. If `refdate` (or `refdatestr`) was in the future, this would be negative.

Comment: Yes, my teacher requires us to use loops. We are using loops in this assignment so that we can get some practice before programming a pump that can assist a donated heart to pump liquid.